# Modified PATH environment variable in Gradle script

Tags: android, gradle, environment-variables, macos-high-sierra

I am running Gradle script. At the beginning I print PATH environment variable:

`println System.getenv( 'PATH' )`

The output is:

`/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin`

But the real PATH environment variable is (printed from terminal):

`/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/sh........`

Question is, why that PATH env variable do not math in Gradle script and in terminal?

Thing is, that I am building Android, which use Gradle as build system. And I have c++ code, which is build by CMake. And in CMake i run some python scripts, which executes some external commands. But when Gradle changes PATH variable, those commands are not found and I am getting an error. It is not an option to use full path, when executing those commands, like:

`/usr/local/bin/my_mega_command`

When I run CMake or python script directly, then everything works as expected.

Comment: Are you running Gradle tasks from the command line, from Android Studio, or by some other means?

Comment: @CommonsWare Good question. Checked. I have such issue building from Android Studio (Build->Make Project). If i run Gradle build command from terminal, then it's working.
I would not say, that it is a problem, but when you want to debug, then it is so embarrassing :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Android Studio does not pass its environment down to the Gradle daemon that it spawns. Usually, we see this in the form of missing custom environment variables, but apparently it affects `PATH` changes as well.

Comment: So, the option would be add path variable to gradle.properties, and then add it to PATH env variable?

Comment: @niparx: Beats me. I am not quite clear why "It is not an option to use full path, when executing those commands", and I do not know if you can change the `PATH` for those commands that you are launching from Gradle.

Comment: "It is not an option to use full path, when executing those commands" - for my machine, those commands (programs) can have one path. My colleague can have another path. So, that script will work for me, bet not for him.

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same issue where running gradle tasks from the Terminal (inside or outside Android Studio) would correctly take the PATH set in the environment (i.e. via .zprofile or any of the other possible methods), but not when running via the Gradle commands from the Android Studio Toolbar. What ended up working for me was changing the JDK version used from the one that came with Android Studio (JDK 11) to JDK 1.8, and suddenly it worked. I don't know why this changes anything, but now the PATH is taken from the environment set in the system and everything works.

[image: How to change the JDK used]